# Git Python log with grep

Tags: python, git, gitpython

On command line I am running

```
git log \
    --merges \
    --grep='^Merge pull request .* in repo/foo from' \
    --grep='^Merged .* to master' \
    tag1..tag2
```

This gives me a list of merge commits to master between the two given tags.

Now I am struggling getting the same from [GitPython](https://github.com/gitpython-developers/GitPython).

What I have tried so far:

```
git.Git(os.getcwd()).log(
    '--merges',
    '--grep="^Merge pull request .* in repo/foo from"',
    '--grep="^Merged .* to master"',
    'tag1..tag2')
```

This works only if I remove the `grep` lines. With `grep` it returns an empty string. Same behaviour here:

```
git.Git(os.getcwd()).execute(['git', 'log',
    '--merges',
    '--grep="^Merge pull request .* in repo/foo from"',
    '--grep="^Merged .* to master"',
    'tag1..tag2'])
```

Another thing I tried:

```
git.repo.fun.rev_parse(repo=git.Repo(), rev='tag1..tag2')
```

This errors out with `BadName` because the `tag1..tag2` doesn't resolve to an object.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The quotes are required by the shell to prevent it from interpreting metacharacters in the strings; but here, you have no shell.

```
git.Git(os.getcwd()).execute(['git', 'log',
    '--merges',
    '--grep=^Merge pull request .* in repo/foo from',
    '--grep=^Merged .* to master',
    'tag1..tag2'])
```

I'm guessing you could also replace `os.getcwd()` with simply `'.'`.

Answer (score 0):

Found the answer. It's about bad quoting. This works:

```
git.Git(os.getcwd()).log(
    '--merges',
    '--grep=^Merge pull request .* in repo/foo from',
    '--grep=^Merged .* to master',
    'tag1..tag2')
```

I think the quotes are necessary on command line to keep the parameter together, but when passing params in Python each param is a string and therefore already "quoted".